# Abaqus UMAT subroutine - error after execution (warning LNK4210?)

Tags: subroutine, abaqus

I am trying to run my first UMAT subroutine with an ABAQUS job.
Fortran compiler seems to be linked to ABAQUS, since Abaqus command

```
abaqus verify -user_std
```

results to pass the check

---

Abaqus/Standard with user subroutines

```
     ...PASS

     Continuing...
```

---

But trying to run the subroutine, an error occurs. The message file of the job reports:

Abaqus/Standard Analysis exited with an error - Please see the  message file for possible error messages if the file exists.*

No message file (.msg) is produced by the software for the job.
The .log file reports the following:

Analysis initiated from SIMULIA established products
Abaqus JOB **JOB NAME**
Abaqus 2020
Abaqus License Manager checked out the following licenses:
Abaqus/Standard checked out 5 tokens from Flexnet server **COMPUTER NAME**
<1019 out of 1024 licenses remain available>.
Begin Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
21/09/2021 12:15:52
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler Classic for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.3.0 Build ***************
Copyright (C) 1985-2021 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

End Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Begin Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Creazione della libreria standardU.lib e dell'oggetto standardU.exp
libirc.lib(fast_mem_ops.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators
End Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
21/09/2021 12:16:00
Begin Analysis Input File Processor
21/09/2021 12:16:00
Run pre.exe
21/09/2021 12:16:05
End Analysis Input File Processor
Begin Abaqus/Standard Analysis
21/09/2021 12:16:05
Run standard.exe
21/09/2021 12:16:06
Abaqus Error: Abaqus/Standard Analysis exited with an error - Please see the
message file for possible error messages if the file exists.
Begin SIM Wrap-up
21/09/2021 12:16:06
Run SMASimUtility.exe
21/09/2021 12:16:06
End SIM Wrap-up
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors

I have checked some previous questions on the web, but it's hard to get further for me.
Any contribution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your environment file:

```
link_sl='LINK /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB /dll /def:%E /out:%U %F %A %L %B'
```

[Source](https://info.simuleon.com/blog/free-fortran-compiler-on-windows-for-abaqus-material-modeling-0)